# Transparent background in fancybox

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

im looking for a solution on how to make white bg transparent but only on iframe popups.
I have this link witch opens other html file with fancybox, its like news popup, and i need to set bg transparent.
I've tried setting #fancybox-outers opacity BUT the thing is, since i have a gallery on same page it makes EVERYTHING that fancybox is showing transparent, including imgs.

Any solutions?

forgot to mention im using version 1.3.4 of fancybox

Comment: Please post a fiddle and your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a condition within the `beforeShow` callback to validate if `type` of content is `iframe` and apply the proper CSS to the `.fancybox-skin` selector then, like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.type == "iframe") {
            $(".fancybox-skin").css({
                backgroundColor: "transparent"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

... so you can use the same script with the same selector for all elements within the gallery.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XRBdd/)**

Comment: ty for your help, but the code worked started working like i wanted by itself, and i have no idea how